# Is this the best way to get the Calling Assembly in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, reflection, uwp, windows-runtime

In Windows 10 UWP (15063), I need to iterate types in calling assemblies to discover types adorned with a specific custom attribute.  I could not find the old System.Reflection.Assembly.Current.GetCallingAssembly() method.   Here's an alternative (*untested* prototype) that I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

namespace UWPContainerUtility
{

    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static Assembly GetCallingAssembly()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(Helpers).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            StackFrame[] frames = GetStackTraceFrames();
            var result = frames.Select(GetFrameAssembly)
                .FirstOrDefault(NotCurrentAssembly);
            return result;

            StackFrame[] GetStackTraceFrames()
            {
                StackTrace trace = null;
                try
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                catch (Exception stacktraceHelper)
                {
                    trace = new StackTrace(stacktraceHelper, true);

                }
                return trace.GetFrames();
            }

            Assembly GetFrameAssembly(StackFrame f)
            {
                return f.GetMethod().DeclaringType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            }

            bool NotCurrentAssembly(Assembly a)
            {
                return !ReferenceEquals(thisAssembly, a);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Is there really currently no other way to do this other than throw a bogus exception? What's the real way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

*Edited example code for clarity

Comment: In testing, this fails. 

The StackTrace only has one frame in it:  itself.

Comment: I can concur. This fails. Throwing an exception in the context of the receiving assembly results in a stack trace with only the receiving assembly. You really need to throw the exception in the calling assembly to make this work. But that would be silly. Of course.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the best way:

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> GetCallingAssemblies()
{
    var s = new StackTrace();
    return s.GetFrames()
        .Select(x => x.GetMethod().DeclaringType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .Where(x => !Equals(x, GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly))
        .Where(x => !x.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft."))
        .Where(x => !x.FullName.StartsWith("System."));
}

Assembly GetCallingAssembly()
{
    return GetCallingAssemblies().First();
}
```

Please note, this is not a drop-in solution for every project. You will need to test and tweak this because the Microsoft. and System. may not fit your scenario. You maybe have more or fewer assemblies to filter out of your list. Picking the first after you filter out the current seems like the most obvious way to get the calling assembly, but depending on how your stack is built, that, too, might need a tweak.

The point is, there is a way, this will get you started.

Best of luck.

Comment: Note this will only work with .NET Core 2, so Fall Creators Update

Comment: A check for `.Where(x => !x.FullName.StartsWith("Windows,")` would probably be common for UWP here. (Yep, it's a comma there.)